# How to handle symbol not found compile error in java?

Tags: java, exception

Is gives the error ship1 not found.
I only declare ship1 only if condiontion is met.
Other wise i have placed else condition which re runs the function.
It is compilation problem, so as i was told earlier ... try catch will not work.

```
    public static int plantNavy(BattleBoard myBattle, int counter) {
    System.out.println("Im innnnn");
    if (counter == 0) {
        System.out.println("\nPlacing Large Ship");
    }
    else if (counter == 1) {
        System.out.println("Placing Medium Ship");
    }
    else if (counter == 2) {
        System.out.println("Placing Medium Ship");
    }
    else if (counter == 3) {
        System.out.println("Placing Small Ship");
    }
    else if (counter == 4) {
        System.out.println("Placing Small Ship");
    }

    System.out.println("Enter 0 to place ship horizontally");
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to place ship vertically");

    String align = shipAlignment.nextLine();
    if (align.length() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Inappropriate value entered. Please enter again");
        plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
    }

    if (align.charAt(0) - 48 == 0 || align.charAt(0) - 48 == 1) {
        if (align.charAt(0) - 48 == 0) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new LargeShip(false);
            }
            else if (counter == 1) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new MediumShip(false);
            }
            else if (counter == 2) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new MediumShip(false);
            }
            else if (counter == 3) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new SmallShip(false);
            }
            else if (counter == 4) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new SmallShip(false);
            }
        }
        if (align.charAt(0) - 48 == 1) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new LargeShip(true);
            }
            else if (counter == 1) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new MediumShip(true);
            }
            else if (counter == 2) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new MediumShip(true);
            }
            else if (counter == 3) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new SmallShip(true);
            }
            else if (counter == 4) {
                BattleShip ship1 = new SmallShip(true);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Inappropriate value entered");
        counter=plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
    }

        System.out.println("Enter Ship Placing position");
        String shipPos = shipPlace.next();
        if (shipPos.length() > 3 || shipPos.length() < 2) {
            System.out.println("Inappropriate target. Please enter again");
            counter = plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
        }
        else if ((int) (shipPos.charAt(1))-48 < 1 || (int)  shipPos.charAt(1)-48 > 10) {
            System.out.println("Inappropriate target. Please enter again");
            counter = plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
        }

        else if ((int) (shipPos.charAt(0)) < 65 || (int) shipPos.charAt(0)> 74) {
            System.out.println("Inappropriate target. Please enter again");
            counter = plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
        }

        int x_pos;
        int y_pos;

        if (shipPos.length() == 3) {
            shipPos = shipPos.charAt(0) + "10";
        }
        if (shipPos.length() == 2) {
            x_pos = (int) (shipPos.charAt(1))-49;
        }
        else {
            x_pos = 9;
        }
        y_pos = (int) (shipPos.charAt(0))-65;

        System.out.println(x_pos);
        System.out.println(y_pos);

        boolean plantCor = myBattle.addShip(ship1,x_pos,y_pos);

        if (plantCor == true) {
            System.out.println(myBattle.printActualBoard());
            counter++;
            return counter;
        }

        if (plantCor == false) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Placement. Place Again in empty area.");
            counter = plantNavy(myBattle,counter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is a compile time error. Exception handling is a run time concept.

Comment: What is `exception `. It should be `Exception`. And brackets..

Comment: Why do you need to handle the case when a variable is not found?  Why not just define it?

Comment: Symbol not found is a compilation error which means your code is not in correct syntax yet. You could post your code. `try/catch` doesn't solve it.

Comment: i have defined the variable in the if condition. else i re run the function.

Comment: This is not going to help, neither us, nor you.

Comment: i tried writing the code but it gives me improper indentation error :S

Comment: You should read about variable scope.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i have written my code. Remember i dont want the function to continue if ship1 is not declared

Comment: i.e., do `if (counter == 0) { ship1 = new LargeShip(false); }` not `if (counter == 0) { BattleShip ship1 = new LargeShip(false); }`

Comment: Although your train of thought exhibits good "data flow" thinking, it shows a deplorable lack of knowledge of the programming language Java. Variables aren't created while the program executes (at least not the way you think they are). Rather, you need to declare one "container" ( = valriable) and then you can fill it in alternative branches of your program. To indicate that nothing "substantial" (= ship) is stored in the container, leave it in its initial assignment state, which should be `null`. You'll have to compare against that value later on...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i tried this technique but it gives an error of missing return statement. return is only done if ship is successfully placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a BattleShip ship1 = null variable at the top of your method and use it:

```
public static int plantNavy(BattleBoard myBattle, int counter) {
   BattleShip ship1 = null;
```

Do not re-declare the variable in your if blocks, just assign to it. i.e., do

```
if (counter == 0) { 
   ship1 = new LargeShip(false); 
}
```

not

```
if (counter == 0) { 
   BattleShip ship1 = new LargeShip(false);  // note the difference!
}
```

Later on you can check if it's null to see if the ship1 has been created.

```
if (ship1 == null) {
   // then no ship1 has been created yet.
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> @HovercraftFullOfEels i tried this technique but it gives an error of missing return statement. return is only done if ship is successfully placed.

Then give it the necessary return statements. Your code has a bunch of returns **nested inside of if statements**. If none of the if statements are true, there's a chance of the method ending without returning anything, and that's not allowed.

One solution is to add a default return statement at the bottom of the method, but if this were my code, I'd chuck the entire method and re-write it, refactoring it into several smaller simpler methods, and getting user interaction out of this method.

---

**Edit 2**
Another problem I see is that you're using recursion in a dangerous and unnecessary way:

```
  if (shipPos.length() > 3 || shipPos.length() < 2) {
     System.out.println("Inappropriate target. Please enter again");
     counter = plantNavy(myBattle, counter);
  }
```

Note that if erroneous input is entered, you're calling the method again **within the same method**, but not realizing that even though the method will call again, after the recursive call returns, the original method will still **run to completion *with* the erroneous input**. My suggestion, avoid recursion here, and again refactoring and simplifying your code will help you to do this.

Instead, get user input in a separate method, verifying the input as it's being obtained (a simple do-while loop will suffice), and then once all input necessary for the placement of a ship is obtained, call your method to place a ship *without* having any user input inside of it.

---

**Edit 3**
Next you'll want to get rid of those magic numbers that you're using, making your code a bear to understand and debug.

Comment: Thank you. Your edit 2 solved my problem. I just added return counter after each recursion statement

Comment: @user3005132: your code might compile, but that recursion is a risky bet, and may bite you.

Comment: I am stuck in another problem. Can you help me on email? I got too many down votes now i cannot ask question. @Hovercraft